# Nilpotent, Idempotent and Involutory Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence, involutions

With exception of the zero matrix, can a matrix be nilpotent $(A^k=0)$ and idempotent $(A^2=A)$ at the same time?

and

With exception of the identity matrix, can a matrix be idempotent and involutory $(A^2=I)$ at the same time?

I think the two answers are negative. Can anyone help me find a counterexample, if any?

Comment: What did you try ? Take a matrix which verifies the involved properties and try to see if you can get something.

Comment: In my attempts I only came to this conclusion, that for the nilpotent-idempotent case there is only the null matrix and for the involuntary-idempotent case there is only the identity matrix.

Comment: Hint: what are the possible eigenvalues of these types of matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $A^2=A$ and there exists a minimal $k\in\Bbb N$ with $A^k=0$. If $k\ge 2$, then $0=A^k=A^2A^{k-2}=AA^{k-2}A^{k-1}$, contradicting minimality of $k$. Therefore $k=1$ and so $A=A^1=0$.

If $A^2=A$ and $A^2=I$, then $A=A^2=I$.